# Breakpoints are not being hit - CLion Full Remote Debug - MakeFile - GDB

Tags: c, makefile, gdb, clion, remote-debugging

It doesn't matter what type of `remote debug` connection I tried.. Full Remote Host, Remote Debug, Remote GDB Server etc.

Actually remote device starts working when I clicked the `debug` button. I can run it from my CLion but it never hits to my breakpoints..

I'm not professional on `remote debugging`, actually it is my second work but this time it is on already working ( readymade ) project on my `Raspberry pi` Lorawan device ( `Debian` ) .
Device connected to my home network and there is a package forwarder app in it. App listens 1680 port.

Normally it is working on `remote device` with no problem. I downloaded the `app` to my computer and built the project successfully in CLion. After I tried lots of things, almost every combination of remote debugging and settings. I understood I'm missing some point and I need help. If you can help me you will save my life

**`Makefile :`**

```
    ### get external defined data

    include ../target.cfg

    ### Application-specific constants

    APP_NAME := lora_pkt_fwd

    ### Environment constants

    LGW_PATH ?= ../libloragw
    LIB_PATH ?= ../libtools
    ARCH ?=
    CROSS_COMPILE ?=

    OBJDIR = obj
    INCLUDES = $(wildcard inc/*.h)

    ### External constant definitions
    # must get library build option to know if mpsse must be linked or not

    include $(LGW_PATH)/library.cfg
    RELEASE_VERSION := `cat ../VERSION`

    ### Constant symbols

    CC := -g $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
    AR := $(CROSS_COMPILE)ar

    CFLAGS := -O2 -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -Iinc -I. -I../libtools/inc
    VFLAG := -D VERSION_STRING="\"$(RELEASE_VERSION)\""

    ### Constants for Lora concentrator HAL library
    # List the library sub-modules that are used by the application

    LGW_INC =
    ifneq ($(wildcard $(LGW_PATH)/inc/config.h),)
      # only for HAL version 1.3 and beyond
      LGW_INC += $(LGW_PATH)/inc/config.h
    endif
    LGW_INC += $(LGW_PATH)/inc/loragw_hal.h

    ### Linking options

    LIBS := -lloragw -ltinymt32 -lparson -lbase64 -lrt -lpthread -lm -lcursor

    ### General build targets

    all: $(APP_NAME)

    clean:
        rm -f $(OBJDIR)/*.o
        rm -f $(APP_NAME)

    ifneq ($(strip $(TARGET_IP)),)
     ifneq ($(strip $(TARGET_DIR)),)
      ifneq ($(strip $(TARGET_USR)),)
    install:
        @echo "---- Copying packet_forwarder files to $(TARGET_IP):$(TARGET_DIR)"
        @ssh $(TARGET_USR)@$(TARGET_IP) "mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)"
        @scp lora_pkt_fwd $(TARGET_USR)@$(TARGET_IP):$(TARGET_DIR)
    install_conf:
        @echo "---- Copying packet_forwarder conf files to $(TARGET_IP):$(TARGET_DIR)"
        @ssh $(TARGET_USR)@$(TARGET_IP) "mkdir -p $(TARGET_DIR)"
        @scp global_conf.json.sx1250.* $(TARGET_USR)@$(TARGET_IP):$(TARGET_DIR)
        @scp global_conf.json.sx1257.* $(TARGET_USR)@$(TARGET_IP):$(TARGET_DIR)
      else
        @echo "ERROR: TARGET_USR is not configured in target.cfg"
      endif
     else
        @echo "ERROR: TARGET_DIR is not configured in target.cfg"
     endif
    else
        @echo "ERROR: TARGET_IP is not configured in target.cfg"
    endif

    ### Sub-modules compilation

    $(OBJDIR):
        mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

    $(OBJDIR)/%.o: src/%.c $(INCLUDES) | $(OBJDIR)
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -I$(LGW_PATH)/inc $< -o $@

    ### Main program compilation and assembly

    $(OBJDIR)/$(APP_NAME).o: src/$(APP_NAME).c $(LGW_INC) $(INCLUDES) | $(OBJDIR)
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(VFLAG) -I$(LGW_PATH)/inc $< -o $@

    $(APP_NAME): $(OBJDIR)/$(APP_NAME).o $(LGW_PATH)/libloragw.a $(OBJDIR)/jitqueue.o
        $(CC) -L$(LGW_PATH) -L$(LIB_PATH) $< $(OBJDIR)/jitqueue.o -o $@ $(LIBS)

    ### EOF
```

I'm sharing my last try screenshots with you : `Full Remot Host`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: Breakpoint Error]

Answer (score 2):

If I add -g to CXXFLAGS in https://github.com/remonbonbon/makefile-example, I can debug the app target just fine.

link -> https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009699119-Debugging-not-working-when-using-the-Makefile-feature-in-2020-2-EAP-

Comment: yes it was like that simple.

CFLAGS := -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -Iinc -I. -I../libtools/inc -g